# Odd/even range in python3.x

Tags: python-3.x

Given an input range (lowest/highest) and choice(odd/even) how can I print the desired output in python? In the below code it doesn't seem to be executing the else condition

```
low = int(input("Lowest number: "))
high = int(input("Highest number: "))
oddeven = input("Do you want to see odd or even numbers: ") 
print(oddeven)

for num in range(low, high):
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        print(num)
    else :
            if (num % 2 == 1):
                print(num)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest solution to implement, would be for you to create two for loops, one for the `even` case and one for the `odd` case, so you only have to check once rather than for each iteration of the for loop:

```
def get_int_input(prompt: str) -> int:
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Error: Enter an integer, try again...")


low = get_int_input("Enter the lowest number in the range (inclusive): ")
high = get_int_input("Enter the highest number in the range (inclusive): ")

valid_odd_even_responses = {"odd", "even"}
odd_even_response = ""
while odd_even_response not in valid_odd_even_responses:
    odd_even_response = input(
        "Do you want to see odd or even numbers: ").lower()

if odd_even_response == "odd":
    for num in range(low, high + 1):
        if num % 2 == 1:
            print(num)
else:
    for num in range(low, high + 1):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print(num)
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter the lowest number in the range (inclusive): -1
Enter the highest number in the range (inclusive): 13
Do you want to see odd or even numbers: even
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
```

Comment: Thanks @Shash Sinha

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- Check your indentation (look that "else")
- "oddeven" is useless
- You don't need num % 2 == 0, just num % 2, because, in python, 0 is 'false' already
- You don't need the second 'if', because the 'else' is already doing the job bifurcating the flow in your program
- If you're learning, try to draw your algorithm with paper and pencil before implementing it

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines are OK:

```
low = int(input("Lowest number: "))
high = int(input("Highest number: "))
```

Here, I add a clarification that tells the user how to answer the question. Your code *does not use this variable*, that is why you get the wrong output.

```
even = int(input("Do you want to see odd (0) or even (1) numbers: "))
```

If the user wants even numbers but `low` is not even, or the other way around, adjust it:

```
if (even and low % 2 == 1) or (not even and low % 2 == 0):
    low += 1
```

Step though all odd or even numbers:

```
print("\n".join(str(x) for x in range(low, high + 1, 2)))
```